# How to add trait bound on struct field in Rust?

Tags: rust, embedded

I am developing some embedded rust and they have struct `struct Pin<const P: char, const N: u8>` and some trait `trait HL`, then by macros they implement `HL` for all `Pin` with `N` from 0 to 15 and it is all pins that may exist.

Next, I need to have some struct, that have `Pin` inside it and want to use some functions from

```rust
impl<const P: char, const N: u8> Pin<P, N>
where
    Self: HL,
{
    // from here
}
```

but I don't know how to tell Rust compiler that `HL` is implemented for Pins that I use :(

The idea can be compressed to this code:

```rust
trait HL {}
struct Pin<const P: char, const N: u8>;

impl<const P: char> HL for Pin<P, 1> {} // <- important that HL is implemented for half-concrete Pin

impl<const P: char, const N: u8> Pin<P, N>
where
    Self: HL,
{
    fn get_x(&self) -> u8 {
        22
    }
}

struct PinWrapper<const P: char, const N: u8> {
    pin: Pin<P, N>,
}

impl<const P: char, const N: u8> PinWrapper<P, N> {
    fn test(&self) {
        println!("pin-get_x: {}", self.pin.get_x());
    }
}
```

which return the error `` method cannot be called on `Pin<P, N>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds `` on `println` line.

I am understanding of the reason behind that error, but dont know how to avoid it.

Please, try to avoid `dyn` and `Box` in solutions :)

Comment: `impl<const P: char, const N: u8> PinWrapper<P, N>` means it will work for any `N`, but you only implement `get_x` if `Pin<P,N>: HL`, which is only implemented for `Pin<P,1>`. It'd work if you did it with `impl<const P: char> PinWrapper<P, 1>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause to your `PinWrapper` implementation that matches the clause that provides `get_x` on `Pin`. Like this:

```
impl<const P: char, const N: u8> PinWrapper<P, N> where Pin<P, N>: HL {
                                               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    fn test(&self) {
        println!("pin-get_x: {}", self.pin.get_x());
    }
}
```